# The text in the JComboBox displays a string but the selection is actually set to null

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` which I create with the following code:

```
employeeDeletetxt = new JComboBox(buildComboBoxmodel("SELECT employee_id, employee_first_name     FROM employees"));
employeeDeletetxt.setSelectedItem(null);
```

Now, when I run the program the selection is set to `null` so nothing is displayed in the combo box. I have an `ActionListener` for a delete button. The `ActionListener` would delete certain records and when this happens I need the data in the `JComboBox` to reflect the recent changes. I use the following code:

```
employeeDeletetxt.removeItem(employeeDeletetxt.getSelectedItem());                      
employeeDeletetxt.setSelectedItem(null);
```

The problem is that the text displayed in the `JComboBox` is not empty after these lines are called. However, the item which the `JComboBox` points to is actually `null` because I get the following error message when I call the `ActionListener` directly after I have called it the previous time:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How can I set the text to be empty?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the context of this combobox. I wrote a little test to simulate this and could not reproduce your problem. After setSelectedItem(null) my combo box text is cleared (with editable false or true). You should provide more source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement what you described and got to this:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class TestGui extends JFrame{

JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Press me!");
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[] {"None", "Help"});


public TestGui() {

    initalise();
}

private void initalise() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.comboBox.setSelectedItem(null);    
    this.contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    this.contentPane.add(comboBox);
    this.contentPane.add(button);

    this.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            comboBox.removeItem(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
            comboBox.setSelectedItem(null);

        }
    });

    this.setContentPane(this.contentPane);

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            new TestGui();
        }
    });
}

}
```

My program runs exactly the way you described. Maybe you can find your problem.

Comment: I have found the problem. I use the following line to allow the user to search for the entry:`AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(employeeDeletetxt2);` This is what is causing the unusual behaviour. Once I remove this line everything works. Is there a way in which I can keep this line and fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think you need the AutoCompleteDecorator. The JComboBox has the oportunity to select entries depending on your input. So in the example above, if the JComboBox is selected and I press "h" the entry "Help" is selected. For what functionality do you need the AutoCompleteDecorator?

Comment: In some cases there are over 100 entries in the JComboBox in my program and I need to provide the user with the ability to type the first few characters in order for him/her to narrow down the search to a few entries. This is why I use the AutoCompleteDecorator. I would like to keep this functionality if possible.

Comment: Why don't you sort the array? The rest should be possible with the standard JComboBox. For example if the String start with "s" i can press "s" several times and iterate over all word which start with "s". Sorry, but I'm not familiar with the AutoCompleteDecorator.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It has been very useful. At least now I know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to the problem and would like to share it with everyone in case someone else has the same problem. As I stated above, the AutoCompleteDecorator was what was causing the problem in the first place. If I removed it then the program would work as expected. However I wanted to provide the user with the ability to search. The solution is to use AutoCompletion instead which is found in the following link: http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/source/AutoCompletion.java. now, in the program, instead of using:
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(employeeDeletetxt);
I use:
    AutoCompletion.enable(employeeDeletetxt); 
This way I allow the user to use the autocomplete option while also being able to set the current selection of the combo box to null.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are setting the current item to null which is different than setting it to an empty string. You can do something like:

employeeDeletetxt.setSelectedItem("").

What I would probably do is create a method that has a loop that creates an array of strings for your combobox and always have the first element be the empty string. That way, once the array is built, you add the rest of your elements retrieved from your query. If your query returns no results, you will just have the text box with the one blank element.

Comment: As stated in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object)) for the parameter to `setSelectedItem (Object anObject)`: _the list object to select; use null to clear the selection_.